# Problem with MySQL Query in Count(*) Column

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am running a MYSQL Query using PHPMYadmin. Below is my query. However, when I export it in CSV/EXCEL, the last column "# of claims" doesn't export properly and it shows some fixed number like 42345 for all rows. Though in PHPMYADMIN, it shows correct. Any Solution?

```
SELECT 
     PATIENT_INSURANCE_ID
        ,PATIENT_ID
        ,(SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM PATIENT WHERE PATIENT_ID = PI.PATIENT_ID) AS 'First Name'
        ,(SELECT LAST_NAME FROM PATIENT WHERE PATIENT_ID = PI.PATIENT_ID) AS 'Last Name'
        ,(SELECT ORG_ID FROM PATIENT WHERE PATIENT_ID = PI.PATIENT_ID) AS 'ORG ID'
        ,INSURANCE_ID
        ,GROUP_ID
        ,INSURANCE_TYPE
        ,INSURANCE_MASTER_ID
        ,(SELECT INSURANCE_NAME FROM PATIENT_INSURANCE_MASTER_LIST WHERE PATIENT_INSURANCE_MASTER_ID = PI.INSURANCE_MASTER_ID) AS 'Insurane Name'
        ,CURRENT
        ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLAIM WHERE INSURANCE_ID IN (SELECT PATIENT_INSURANCE_ID FROM PATIENT_INSURANCE WHERE INSURANCE_MASTER_ID = PI.INSURANCE_MASTER_ID)) AS '# of Claims'
FROM PATIENT_INSURANCE AS PI
WHERE INSURANCE_MASTER_ID IN (SELECT PATIENT_INSURANCE_MASTER_ID FROM PATIENT_INSURANCE_MASTER_LIST WHERE ORG_ID ='10000797' AND INSURANCE_NAME LIKE '%delete%')
```

Pleas help in this.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem but the sub-queries should be replaced by joins..(in my opinion)

Comment: Salmon - Everything working fine except last column Count(*) - MYSQL shows correct value in this column but when I export it, all values in this column changed to a fixed value like 45325

Comment: Please show sample data.  Its probably overflowing teh default data type size/limit

Comment: @RohitGupta - Thanks this is resolve already!

Comment: Perhaps you should post it as an answer